# Wordpress define own variable for theme

Tags: wordpress, loops, variables, global

I am quite familiar with wordpress template tag and working on new theme. I want to make bunch of variables which I will use quite often in my theme. Few are very simple template tag and few my own HTML structure to reuse in other template files.

Fore e.g I want to make variable for `the_ttle()` or `the_permalink` like `$title = the_title();` or `$perma = the_permalink();` so whenever I will add `$title` or `$perma` in template file it will echo the title or permalink.

and for html structure e.g I am defining recent post loop.

```
$recentloop = <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
get_thumbnail();
the_title();
get_post_meta(); etc.....
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Something like above I am not sure if there is anything wrong :(

So to make it happen where I should define these variables so I can use it for every template files.

I read this topic http://wordpress.org/support/topic/passing-php-variable-between-template-files#post-1506298 but no idea how and where to place `global $variable`

I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are still having such problems.

As the title & permalink will update in every post loop, you shouldn't make it a variable that is available everywhere. But if you insist to do so, you can put the variable in `functions.php`.